# Field in component becomes null between ngOnInit and click event

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Typical component:

```
@Component (
selector: 'mycomp',
template: '<div>mycomp</div>',
)
class MyComp implements OnInit {
String testobj;
void mymeth() {
  context.callMethod('alert', [testobj]);
}
@override
ngOnInit() {
  testobj = '123';
  context.callMethod('alert', ['initialized']);
}}
```

placed in app root component like that:

```
import 'mycomp_component.dart';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
@Component (
selector: 'testcomp',
template: '''
<button (click)="testModeler()">load</button>
<mycomp></mycomp>''',
providers: const[MyComp],
directives: const[MyComp],
)
class TestComponent {
MyComp myComp;
TestComponent(this.myComp);
void testModeler() {
  myComp.mymeth();
}}
```

testobj initializes on page load, but when I click a "load" button testobj is null! Why it happens and how to make it working properly?

Also: how to diagnose problems like that in dart, is there a possibility to put a breakpoint on class or field? I don't find a way in dartium/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular creates an instance per provider.

If you use

```
providers: const[MyComp],
```

this provider will hold an instance of the `MyComp` class. This will not be an Angular component, just an instance of the plain class. Angular won't call `ngOnInit` because it is not a component.
This instance will be passed to the constructor.

Angular creates a component for `<mycomp></mycomp>` though and calls `ngOnInit` on this instance.
This is another instance than the once created by the provider.

To get hold of a reference of a component in the template you can use `@ViewChild()` or `@ContentChild()`

```
@Component (
  selector: 'testcomp',
  template: '''
    <button (click)="testModeler()">load</button>
    <mycomp></mycomp>''',
    directives: const[MyComp],
)
class TestComponent {
  @ViewChild(MyComp) MyComp myComp;

  TestComponent();

  void testModeler() {
    myComp.mymeth();
  }
}
```

[How can I select an element in a component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template/35209681#35209681) provides some additional explanation. It's for TypeScript but most things should work with small syntax changes.

https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide should also contain some info.

Comment: It doesn't work without "provider" string with exception: No provider found for MyComp.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the constructor parameter. You can't inject a component from the view this way.